# Display Identity seed when creating a new sql object from MVC application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application I allow users to add an object to a database table through a "Create" controller/view using Entity Framework database first design.  When testing I have no data in this table currently so the first object should have an ID of 1.

But in the view, the field for ID is empty. Again, it should be 1 since this is the first object and it's picking up from the data model. The next time they add another object, the ID should be 2...etc.

I have set IsIdentity to Yes.  I have set Identity seed to 1.

Programatically what am I missing for the ID field to display 1 when this is the first item to be added to the table.

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Controller**

```
// GET: Products/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
// POST: Products/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ProductId,...Other columns")] Product product)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Products.Add(product);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(product);
    }
```

**Model**

```
public int ProductId { get; set; }
```

**SQL**

```
[dbo].[Product]
(
  [ProductId] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGa3i.png

Comment: You don't explicitly set identity columns - it is done automatically when the object is saved.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense, but I have the column defined as NOT NULL.  So if I don't define a ProductId I get a validation error message that says "ProductId is required" because it is.  So I guess the goal is to populate this field with what the Id WILL be.

Comment: You should not be using an `<input>` (EditorFor) for autogenerated Ids. Display them if you like, but the Id will not be known until you save it. It's a very common pattern.

Comment: Right, that's exactly what I want.  I do want to display it, but it's not picking up that the first one should be 1. I will need to remove the option to edit it but I at least want to display it. But again for some reason it's not picking up a 1. Not sure if it will pick up a 2 for the second entry either...

Comment: In the Create it is not known, once saved it is - so your Index, Update and Delete would be able to display it. If you have a shared view for Create/Update you could add conditional logic to display the ID if desired. What if the user cancels before the post? That's the beauty - let EF handle it. If you are seeking control over the value then don't use Identity - go to GUIDs or a non-surrogate key.

Comment: [Here is an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part6) of what I mean. "Since our database automatically gives a Movie an ID, let's remove those fields that reference model.Id from our Create View. Remove the 7 lines after <legend>Fields</legend> as they show the ID field that we don't want.".

Comment: I was way over-complicating this.  You're exactly right.  We don't want the ID on the create, only on Edit and Delete. I removed the field all together on the Create view and tested.  Database created the object with an ID of 1 as expected.  Thanks for your help!